# How to plot confident interval from a df in python

Tags: python, confidence-interval

I am trying to put in a confident interval into my plot with `.fill_between` , however, the standard deviations are based on another column. For example,

[image]

I am plotting a line with

```
real = df['real'].values
sd = df['S.D'].values
pt.plot(real.index, real.values, color = 'blue')
pt.fill_between(real.index, real.values - (sd*2), real.values + (sd*2),
             color='grey', alpha=0.2)
```

Am I doing it right? The output shows a weird confident interval (out of the table range!).

Comment: You are using a variable called sd and not the column sd from your dataframe

Comment: @Benedictanjw I made sd equal to the S.D. column (in line 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for not seeing that in your code. There's no problem with the way you're trying to do things but I think you may have made some typos in the bit of code you copied and pasted into SO. The below works perfectly:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Real': [3,1,3,3,9,0,4,3,2,3], 
    'S.D.': [0.2,0.5,0.1,1,0.4,0.6,0.8,2,0.3,0.2]}, index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

plt.plot(df.index, df['Real'], color = 'blue')
plt.fill_between(df.index, df['Real'] - (df['S.D.']*2), df['Real'] + (df['S.D.']*2),
             color='grey', alpha=0.2)

plt.show()
```

[image]